# Line Integral of $F(x,y)=(2y,-3x)$ around unit circle.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I encountered the above problem earlier, and had issues solving it.  If we let $C$ be the unit circle, and $F(x,y)=(2y,-3x)$, by Divergence theorem we have that $$\oint_{\partial C} F(x,y)\cdot \hat{n}\,\mathrm{d}S=\iint_{C}\nabla\cdot F(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}A=\iint_{C}0\,\mathrm{d}A=0$$

But, when I introduce the standard parametrization of the circle (I'm not too concerned with the orientation that I'm integrating the line integral around in this problem), $\gamma(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$, I get:
\begin{align}
\oint_{\partial C}F(x,y)\,\cdot\hat{n}\mathrm{d}S&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}F(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} (2\sin t,-3\cos t)\cdot (-\sin t,\cos t)\,\mathrm{d}t \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}-2\sin^2t-3\cos^2t\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^{2\pi}-2-\cos^2t\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}

At this point, the particular value the integral becomes ($-5\pi$) isn't that important, as it's decidedly nonzero, and disagrees with my calculation via divergence theorem.  As my calculation via divergence theorem makes more sense to me, it seems clear that my line integral calculation is wrong.  Additionally, I've checked via Mathematica the value of $\int_0^{2\pi}(2\sin t,-3\cos t)\cdot (-\sin t,\cos t)\,\mathrm{d}t$, which ends up going $-5\pi$, so the mistake isn't there.  This leads me to believe I have a problem with my parametrization.  Can someone help me spot it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You are wrong because $\gamma'(t)$ is the tangent vector to the curve $\gamma(t)$, not the **normal**. The normal to a circle at a point $(x(t),y(t))$ with  your parametrization is $\vec n =(\cos t, \sin t)$. use this in the dot product and you find the correct result.